# Setting PropertyBag values in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, property-bag

I am trying to set some property bag values in SharePoint Online, specifically around SharePoint Designer access. The code below runs without error, but I do not see the propertybag value being updated in `/_layouts/15/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx`. Is it not possible to update PropertyBag values in SharePoint Online?

```
$SiteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
$web = $context.Site.RootWeb
$props =  $web.AllProperties
$props.FieldValues["allowdesigner"] = 0
$web.Update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works for me with a couple small changes. Instead of manipulating the `FieldValues` object, just manipulate the `AllProperties` object directly. Also, set the value to a string, not an int:

```
web.AllProperties["allowdesigner"] = "0";
```

Here's the full helper method I use:

```
public static void AddWebProperty(ClientContext ctx, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(web);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    web.AllProperties[propertyName] = propertyValue;
    web.Update();            
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: I knew I was effing something up somewhere. Adapting this to the existing PowerShell I had then set the desired properties.

Comment: You don't need to load properties. It's just unnecessary traffic.

Comment: @dstarkowski I wasn't sure, and never bothered to verify. I've edited the post to remove that. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Derek's answer solves problem for property bag in general, but there's also [`Site.AllowDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.allowdesigner.aspx) property you could use for your specific case.

Comment: Both great answers

Answer (score 0):

PFB script to update in SP online to disable all controls in Designer settings in Site Collection

```
$url="SC URL"

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 

$username= "Username";
$password=ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force;

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username , $password);

$ctx.Credentials = $credentials ;

$web=$ctx.site;

$ctx.load($web);

$web.AllowDesigner=0;

$web.AllowMasterPageEditing=0;

$web.AllowRevertFromTemplate=0;

$web.ShowUrlStructure=0;

$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```